# why are my form_alter changes not saving?

Tags: forms

I have a form_alter function in my .theme file, I am trying to change some of the text in my user_register form, and some of the text I change is changing, but some of it shows that it is changing if I print that field out after changing it, but the change doesn't show up on the page. Do any of y'all know why?

Here is the function:

```
function [site_name]_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['account']['mail']['#title'] = "Enter your email"; //These changes show up on the page
  $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = "Enter your business email to be used to sign in to [Site Name]."; //These changes show up on the page

  $form['field_first_name']['widget']['#title'] = "Enter your name";
//These changes show up if I print these variables after these lines, but the changes don't show up on the page
  $form['field_first_name']['widget']['#description'] = "Enter your business email to be used to sign in to [Site Name]."; 
//These changes show up if I print these variables after these lines, but the changes don't show up on the page
  /*$form['field_account_type']['#theme_wrappers'] = array('container');
  $form['field_account_type']['widget']['#title'] = " Step 2: Select your current role.";
  $form['field_account_type']['widget']['#description'] = "Your role will help us determine what type of account to create.";*/ //These changes worked when they were being used, but I don't need them anymore
  $form['field_receive_updates']['widget']['value']['#description'] = "";

  $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = "Request Registration"; //This change shows up on the page
}
```

Comment: Look deeper into `$form['field_first_name']['widget']` etc, there will be further sub-arrays. The one containing, for example, `'#type' => 'textfield'`, is probably the one you want to target. For the first example that will probably be `$form['field_first_name']['widget']['value']['#description']`

Comment: @Clive You are a wonderful human being! That did it! I just needed to add a [0] to your code snippet and it worked! $form['field_first_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#title'] Could you add that in as an answer so that I can check that as the correct answer?